# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MutableSet'

Tags: python, bittorrent

I installed [BitTornado](https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado) without root access  by downloading the zip and running command 'pip install -e path/to/bittornado/'. The installation was successful but when I tried using it for downloading the file, the following error occurred --
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MutableSet'.
The following screenshot has the details.

[image: BitTornado Error]

I'm new to Python. If someone know what's happening, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitTornado only supports python3 (and not python2.x).  The specific error is due to a change in python3 which makes imports absolute by default (unless the relative import syntax is used) -- as such it is importing the `BitTorando.Types.collections` module for `import collections`.

I'd suggest making a python3 [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and installing BitTornado there. (Or if you want a system-wide installation, use `pip3 install ...`)

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. Your answer helped. For anyone looking for older versions of Python; [2.6](https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado/tree/python2.6) and [2.7](https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado/tree/python2.7) are also available.

Comment: Ah yes, but these branches are no longer maintained from what I can tell (2.6 is dead, 2.7 is receiving bugfix / security only it seems)